# Make UPDATE with JOIN apply to all records

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
TABLE bon                       TABLE order         TABLE payed 
b_id | total | payed | diff     id | b_id | amm     id | b_id | amm 
-----+-------+-------+------    ---+------+-----    ---+------+-----
  1  |   0   |   0   |  0        1 |   1  |   5      1 |   2  | -10
-----+-------+-------+------    ---+------+-----    ---+------+-----
  2  |   0   |   0   |  0        2 |   2  |   5      2 |   3  |  -5  
-----+-------+-------+------    ---+------+-----    ---+------+-----
  3  |   0   |   0   |  0        3 |   1  |  15
                                ---+------+-----
                                 4 |   3  |  10
                                ---+------+-----
                                 5 |   2  |  15
                                ---+------+-----
                                 6 |   2  |  20
```

If I want to update the totals in **bon** for only one id, I do:

```
UPDATE `bon`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
        SUM(`amm`) AS `total`
        FROM `order` 
        WHERE `b_id`=2
    ) AS s1

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
        COALESCE(SUM(`amm`),0) AS `payed`
        FROM `payed` 
        WHERE `b_id`=2
    ) AS s2

    SET
    `bon`.`total` = s1.`total`,
    `bon`.`payed` = s2.`payed`,
    `bon`.`diff` = s1.`total` + s2.`payed`
WHERE `b_id`=2;
```

That updates **id 2** correctly to

```
b_id | total | payed | diff   
-----+-------+-------+------
  2  |   40  |  -10  |  30
```

However, I try to update **ALL** id's with:

```
UPDATE `bon`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
        `b_id`,
        SUM(`amm`) AS `total`
        FROM `order` 
    ) AS s1 ON bon.`b_id`=s1.`b_id`

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
        `b_id`,
        SUM(`amm`) AS `payed`
        FROM `payed` 
    ) AS s2 ON bon.`b_id`=s2.`b_id`

    SET
    `bon`.`total` = s1.`total`,
    `bon`.`payed` = COALESCE(s2.`payed`,0),
    `bon`.`diff` = s1.`total` + COALESCE(s2.`payed`,0)
```

Sadly, this updates no rows. So where am I going wrong in this one?

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6689c/1)

**EDIT:** I have found a solution and posted it below. Don't know if it is the best way to do this, but it works (suggestions still welcome).

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't worked out a solution yet, I think there are some problems with your second query.

1) Let us look at your first inner query:

```
SELECT
`b_id`,
SUM(`amm`) AS `total`
FROM `order`
```

This in the first place will pull *all* rows from `order`, but your computed column which you have aliased as `total` will have the *same value in every row*.

This is probably not what you want. Joining the result set from that `SELECT` with the `bon` table does *not* mean that MySQL applies some magic behind the scenes and groups that result set by the column which is used in the `JOIN`.

Instead, at first the cross product from your table `bon` and the result set from the first `SELECT` is built (this cross product also has the *same* value for `total` in each row). The `JOIN` then just filters the rows where `bin.b_id` and `s1.b_id` is the same.

Of course, each of these rows still has the same `total` value, so even if it did the update, you would get wrong results.

The remedy would be to add a grouping by `b_id` in the `SELECT` statement. This would cause the `total` to be computed correctly, i.e. per `b_id`. You then would use the *grouped* `b_id` for the `JOIN`.

The same applies for your second `SELECT` inner query.

2) You are doing an `INNER JOIN` with a `SELECT` from table `payed`. That means the result will not contain any rows which are not in `payed`. With your example data, the result will not contain rows where `b_id` would be `1` (because your `payed` table does not contain such rows).

This problem is not that easy to solve. One solution would be to make sure that there is every `b_id` in the `payed` table before running the query. But maybe you are just happy when the IDs which do not exist in the `payed` table are not updated.

If you describe in more detail what you would like, we eventually could work out a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your extended answer. I only want to update `bon` with the sums of the corresponding values in the other two tables. There's always at least one entry in `order` for every `b_id`, but in `payed` it could be missing. I played around with all kinds of JOINS, to no avail. I found a solution by ditching all the JOINS. Don't know if it is the best, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, skipping all the JOINS. Maybe not the best answer, but it works (suggestions are still welcome):

```
UPDATE `bon`
    SET
    `bon`.`total` = 
        (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(`amm`),0)
            FROM `order`
            WHERE `order`.`b_id`=`bon`.`b_id`
            ),
    `bon`.`payed` = 
        (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(`amm`),0)
            FROM `payed`
            WHERE `payed`.`b_id`=`bon`.`b_id`
            ),
    `bon`.`diff` = 
            (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(`amm`),0)
            FROM `order` 
            WHERE `order`.`b_id`=`bon`.`b_id`
            )+
            (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(`amm`),0)
            FROM `payed`
            WHERE `payed`.`b_id`=`bon`.`b_id`
            )
```